# How to make a web service (preferably using PHP) that can be requested to get JSON objects by the android app

Tags: php, android, database, json, webserver

I am making an Android App which interacts with remote server's database and communicate with each other by passing JSON object to and from.

I need to know how to write such a service on my server (preferably in PHP) to which the android app can make request and on receiving the request, the server processes and makes a JSON object and passes that to the android app.

Also, i need to know, when this service is running on the server, on *WHICH* URL will the android app make request?

For example, if android app have to request to sever to fetch data for parameters:
name: Apple
location: US
then, i guess the android app will have to request the server in form of:
 www.example.com?name='Apple"&location='US'

So how to make such a service running on the remote server?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can mark the post as solved that really helped you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best example you can refer for this is http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/. It has complete code[php+ android] with simple explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method that request remote php file that responses to post or get request. if you want to use post request , you can use method below. and you have to add Internet permisson to your manifest file. As you see below , you can add parameters as being  key -value pair.

```
       public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/webservice.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Apple"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locaction", "US"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();  
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,res);


} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
  }
```

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient